# Scrape the current share price data from the ASX

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula, stock

I am trying to scrape the current share price data from the ASX into a Google spreadsheet.

I am NOT using `=googlefinance("ASX.NEA","price")` for instantanious delayed price as the resolution rounds the value for penny stocks.

I am NOT using `=INDEX(googlefinance("ASX.NEA","price", today()-10, today()),2,2)` for historical prices this can not get the current days price even though resolution price is accurate.

- url: `https://www.asx.com.au/asx/share-price-research/company/NEA`
- xpath (xPath Finder):
  `/html/body/section[3]/article/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/company-summary/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span`
- equation: `=IMPORTXML(url, xpath)`
- result: #N/A Error imported content is empty

Other xpaths I have tried are:

- xpath: `//table/tbody//span`
- xpath: `//span[@ng-show="share.last_price"]`
- xpath: `//span[@ng-show="share.last_price"]`

When I view page source, the latest share price is loaded via javascript.

Example: Share price is 0.910

[image: CHrome inspect element]

Answer (score 3):

Alternate Solution using Apps Scripts (javascript)

```
function AsxPrice(asx_stock) {
  var url = "https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/share/" + asx_stock +"/";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(content);
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var last_price = json["last_price"]; 
  return last_price;
}
```

This is far more efficient that `importXML()` or `ImportHTML()` as HTML is bloated, the above url is a jsonresult.

For other large stock exchanges (json source can be found at) :

EU
USA

Comment: Handy workaround now that GoogleFinance calls appear to be broken for US domiciled funds (like VTS/VEU)

(since Tuesday 21-Jan-2020)

Comment: In one case in order to avoid the "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"  I had to use var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(content))  because the response was HTML instead of JSON.